# progressbar in Tkinter with a label inside

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

Is It possible to improve my progressbar in Tkinter-Python adding a label in the middle (ex: reading file)?

I tried to find a elegant coding solution but without a real result

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import time

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("ProgressBar example")
        self.master.minsize(200, 100)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.start_ind = Button(self, text='Start indeterminate', command=self.start_ind, activeforeground="red")
        self.start_ind.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.pbar_ind = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="indeterminate")
        self.pbar_ind.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

   def start_ind(self):
        for i in xrange(50):
            self.pbar_ind.step(1)
            self.update()
            # Busy-wait
            time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__=="__main__":
   d = MainWindow()
   d.mainloop()
```

Comment: The documentation makes no mention of embedding a label in the progressbar widget, which usually means that it's unsupported. You would have to look at writing a custom widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progressbar with Percentage Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896881/progressbar-with-percentage-label)

Answer (score 8):

I added the label inside the progressbar by creating a custom ttk style layout. The text of the label is changed by configuring the style:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar, Style, Button
from time import sleep


root = Tk()
s = Style(root)
# add the label to the progressbar style
s.layout("LabeledProgressbar",
         [('LabeledProgressbar.trough',
           {'children': [('LabeledProgressbar.pbar',
                          {'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'ns'}),
                         ("LabeledProgressbar.label",   # label inside the bar
                          {"sticky": ""})],
           'sticky': 'nswe'})])

p = Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=300,
                style="LabeledProgressbar")
p.pack()

# change the text of the progressbar, 
# the trailing spaces are here to properly center the text
s.configure("LabeledProgressbar", text="0 %      ")

def fct():
    for i in range(1, 101):
        sleep(0.1)
        p.step()
        s.configure("LabeledProgressbar", text="{0} %      ".format(i))
        root.update()

Button(root, command=fct, text="launch").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why it looks more like a button instead of a progressbar in Windows?

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan Maybe that's because of Windows default theme which is not as customizable as other themes. Try to add `s.theme_use("clam")` just after `s = Style(root)`.

Comment: For me,  changing the `pbar` child to `('LabelledProgressbar.pbar', {'sticky': 'nswe'})` centers the label w/o trailing spaces.

Comment: Also, the solution works for a single bar, because multiple bars will share the same style... and text property.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a text Label and putting it in the same row/column and setting it the same size like so:

```
self.Lab = Label(self,length=200)
self.Lab.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=2,padx=2,sticky=E+W+N+S))
```

But you would want to put it after the progress bar widget.

Comment: This doesn't work. It just covers up the progress bar, and labels cannot have transparent backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution for it, which works.

I use a label that is placed on top of the progressbar and the background of the label updates in sync with the progressbar using relwidth and the same color as the progressbar.

```py
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

#Tkinter window
class GUI(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, progress_frame):
        super().__init__(progress_frame)
        self.progress_frame = progress_frame
        self.progress_frame.geometry('300x100')
        self.progress_frame.title('Progressbar')
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.progress_frame, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
        # place the progressbar
        self.progressbar.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, ipady=3)
        # initialize label
        self.value = StringVar()
        self.value.set(self.update_progress_label("0 MB/s"))
        self.value_label = Label(self.progress_frame, textvariable=self.value, font='default 10', borderwidth=0)
        #set background to grey
        self.value_label['bg'] = '#e6e6e6'
        self.value_label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)
        self.current_value = 0
        self.start_download()

    def update_progress_label(self, mb_s): #the value you want to show in the label
        return f"{self.progressbar['value']}% / {mb_s}"

    def start_download(self): #start thread that does calculation
        download_thread = Download()
        download_thread.start()
        self.monitor(download_thread)

    def monitor(self, download_thread): # monitor download progress
        """ Monitor the download thread """
        if download_thread.is_alive():
            progress = download_thread.value
            # update the label
            self.value.set(self.update_progress_label(download_thread.mb_s))
            widget_x, widget_width = self.value_label.winfo_x(), self.value_label.winfo_width()  # get position and width of text label
            progressbar_pixellen = self.progressbar.winfo_width() # get total width of progressbar
            # get the current position in pxl of progressbar
            calculation_ppixel = progress*progressbar_pixellen/100
            # get the overlap with the text label
            calculation_ptext = calculation_ppixel-widget_x+self.progressbar.winfo_x()
            # ensure that no negative value is set
            calculation_text = max(calculation_ptext/widget_width, 0)
            if calculation_text>0:  # if calculation_text (relwidth) is 0 it will still show a small bar, so don't update the label
                # update the label with the new text value and the color of the progressbar
                self.pblabel = Label(self.value_label, textvariable=self.value, font='default 10', background='#06b025', borderwidth=0, anchor="w")
                # relwidth will only show the given percentage of the text in the color
                self.pblabel.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", relwidth=calculation_text)
            # update the progressbar progress
            self.progressbar['value'] = progress
            # update the label
            self.value_label.update_idletasks()
            # rerun this method in 100ms
            self.after(100, lambda: self.monitor(download_thread))


class Download(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.picture_file = None
        self.value = 0
        self.mb_s = 0
    def run(self):
        """ do some calculation like downloading a file """
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.value = i
            self.mb_s = "100 MB/s"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    progress_frame = Tk()
    app = GUI(progress_frame)
    app.mainloop()
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfY7r.png)