# tkinter progressbar - linked to function?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm having some trouble understanding the `Progressbar` widget in tkinter (python 2.7) I went [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html#progressbar) and [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Progressbar.html) but I still don't understand how to link the `Progressbar` itself (in "determinate" mode) to my functions.

Does anyone have any examples on how to link the completion of functions to the progress-bar updating? I did research this, I just can't find any helpful information. A note on my (already working) code - a .txt file is created as the code runs that prints the total number of functions and the current function that is being run. I would like to link the `progressbar` with the information in these .txt files.

### Edit

More specifically, how do I get value to change to be the correct number?

Comment: See some code in question [Using the same progressbar in tkinter for several computation in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764575/using-the-same-progressbar-in-tkinter-for-several-computation-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Working example - you can see current value and max value in both types progressbars.

--

You can use `self.var_ind.set()` or `self.var_det.set()` in your function (inside class `MainWindow`) to update progressbar.

--

If your function is outside class you have to call it with `self.var_ind` or `self.var_det` as argument.

```
 your_function(self.var_det)
```

and inside function use it

```
 def your_function(progress):
     progress.set(10) # set new value
     progress.set( progress.get() + 23 ) # add 23 to current value
```

I use `var_ind.set()` and `self.var_det.set()` in `BEGIN`, `SET 23`, `END` to set new value.

--

If you have to set `max` in progressbar you will need add `self.pbar_ind` or `self.pbar_det` as argument too.

```
 your_function(self.var_det, self.pbar_det)
```

and inside function use it

```
 def your_function(progress, bar):

     bar.config(maximum=200) # set max to 200

     bar.step() # add 1 to current value
     bar.step(23) # add 23 to current value

     progress.set(10) # set new value
     progress.set( progress.get() + 23 ) # add 23 to current value
```

---

**EDIT:** new example with more buttons:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class MainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("ProgressBar example")
        #self.master.minsize(400, 100)
        self.grid(sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        self.var_ind = IntVar(self)

        self.pbar_ind = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=400, mode="indeterminate", variable=self.var_ind, maximum=100)
        self.pbar_ind.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S, columnspan=3)

        Label(self, text="indeterminate").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.lab_ind_var = Label(self, text="VAR:")
        self.lab_ind_var.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.lab_ind_max = Label(self, text="MAX:")
        self.lab_ind_max.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        self.var_det = IntVar(self)

        self.pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=400, mode="determinate", variable=self.var_det, maximum=100)
        self.pbar_det.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S, columnspan=3)

        Label(self, text="determinate").grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.lab_det_var = Label(self, text="VAR:")
        self.lab_det_var.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        self.lab_det_max = Label(self, text="MAX:")
        self.lab_det_max.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="ANIMATION:").grid(row=4, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='START', command=self.animation_start).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='STOP', command=self.animation_stop).grid(row=4, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="SET:").grid(row=5, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='BEGIN', command=self.set_begin).grid(row=5, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='END', command=self.set_end).grid(row=5, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="SET:").grid(row=6, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='23', command=lambda:self.set(23)).grid(row=6, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='77', command=lambda:self.set(77)).grid(row=6, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="SET:").grid(row=7, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='+23', command=lambda:self.set_plus(23)).grid(row=7, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='-77', command=lambda:self.set_plus(-77)).grid(row=7, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="STEP:").grid(row=8, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='+1', command=lambda:self.step(1)).grid(row=8, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='-10', command=lambda:self.step(-10)).grid(row=8, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        Label(self, text="MAX:").grid(row=9, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        Button(self, text='100', command=lambda:self.max(100)).grid(row=9, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        Button(self, text='200', command=lambda:self.max(200)).grid(row=9, column=2, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #-----

        self.update_labels_after = False
        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def animation_start(self):
        self.update_labels_after = True

        self.pbar_ind.start() # .start(1)
        self.pbar_det.start() # .start(1)

        self.update_labels()

    def animation_stop(self):
        self.update_labels_after = False

        self.pbar_ind.stop()
        self.pbar_det.stop()

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def set_begin(self):
        self.var_ind.set( 0 )
        self.var_det.set( 0 )

        self.update_labels()

    def set_end(self):
        self.var_ind.set( self.pbar_ind.cget('maximum') )
        self.var_det.set( self.pbar_det.cget('maximum') )

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def set(self, val):
        self.var_ind.set( val )
        self.var_det.set( val )

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def set_plus(self, val):
        self.var_ind.set( self.var_ind.get() + val )
        self.var_det.set( self.var_det.get() + val )

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def step(self, val=1):
        self.pbar_ind.step(val) # .step()
        self.pbar_det.step(val) # .step()

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def max(self, val=1):
        self.pbar_ind.config(maximum=val)
        self.pbar_det.config(maximum=val)

        self.update_labels()

    #-----          

    def update_labels(self):

        self.lab_ind_var.config(text='VAR: %d' % (self.var_ind.get()))
        self.lab_ind_max.config(text='MAX: %d' % (self.pbar_ind.cget('maximum')))

        self.lab_det_var.config(text='VAR: %d' % (self.var_det.get()))
        self.lab_det_max.config(text='MAX: %d' % (self.pbar_det.cget('maximum')))

        if self.update_labels_after:
            self.after(50, self.update_labels)

if __name__=="__main__":
   MainWindow().mainloop()
```

(To create example I used part of code from 
[Gianni Spear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493192/gianni-spear) question [Using the same progressbar in tkinter for several computation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764575/using-the-same-progressbar-in-tkinter-for-several-computation-in-python))

[image]

Comment: This is amazing and just what I was looking for!! Thank you from a very grateful python Tkinter newbie :)

Comment: One question though - why does it only go to Max-1?? For example, I wrote the code so that the maximum would be 5 (I will eventually have 5 tasks for it to complete) but VAR only goes to 4 and then restarts. How do I make VAR go to MAX?

Comment: You have to use `.set(5)`. Maybe you have list or `range(5)` which gives you five elements `0,1,2,3,4`