# Python tkinter can't use "pyimage4" as iconphoto

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my program I have a main window and I would like to add a loading window before that main window will initialize but I can't add icon for this loading window. There my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.title('BINGO')

class Loader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loader = Tk()
        try:
            img = PhotoImage(r'C:\menu-16.png')
            self.loader.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.loader._w, img)
        except:
            self.loader.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
        self.loader.title('BINGO')
        self.frame = LabelFrame(self.loader)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=2,padx=2)
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text='Loading...', font=('segoe', 12))
        self.label.pack(side=TOP, pady='4')
        self.progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, mode='determinate', length=464)
        self.progress_bar.pack(side=TOP, fill='x', pady='20')
        self.loader.update()

    def bar(self, value):
        self.progress_bar['value'] += value
        self.loader.update()

    def destroy(self):
        self.loader.destroy()

loader = Loader()
loader.bar(5)

class Main_Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mframe = LabelFrame(root)
        pass

loader.bar(100)

root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(r'C:\menu-16.png'))

loader.destroy()

Application = Main_Window()
root.mainloop()
```

In this case "loader" run as tool window without icon but main "Main_window" have it. How to fix this ?

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm found solution of my problem:

I had to **change** `self.loader = Tk()` **into** `self.loader = Toplevel()`

Answer (score 0):

Check for your code. Progress bar is defined in `tkinter.tkk` so you need to import `tkinter.tkk` as

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
....
img = PhotoImage(r'C:\menu-16.png'))
...
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(r'C:\menu-16.png'))
```

as there is an extra `)`, remove the `)` and add `file=` to the PhotoImage and remove the `ttk` from `ttk.Progressbar`.

```
img = PhotoImage(file=r'C:\menu-16.png')
....
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file=r'C:\menu-16.png'))
```

And you have defined class as `Main_Window()` and you are calling as `Main_window()`.

[tkinter gui with progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768577/tkinter-gui-with-progress-bar)

Comment: ty, this mistakes i had only here in example. In real code all clear and i'm still can't understand why loader can't initialize icon :(

Comment: Comment the loader.destroy() to see it action. Its working with the icon.

Comment: Here code, that is not my main but all works same. Try run it. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGE-Xx_3qGtYifoEjyNq2gIzCvR4kQwX

Comment: The code works fine, just change the `self.loader.attributes('-toolwindow', True)` to `self.loader.attributes('-alpha', True)` since `-toolwindow` is not a valid attribute you can use these `-alpha`, `-fullscreen`, `-modified`, `-notify`, `-titlepath`, `-topmost`, or  `-transparent`.

Comment: this line take effect `self.loader.attributes('-toolwindow', True)` only if error in `self.loader.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self.loader._w, img)`. Why tkinter cannot setup icon ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204941/discussion-between-santosh-aryal-and-acamori).