# Manual progress bar python

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

Im trying to make a code so that it displays all numbers from 1 to 100 to show as its loading something.

```
for i in range(101):
        self.new = Label(self.label_progress, text=i)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.new.place(in_= self.label_progress)
        if i == 100:
            self.new1=Label(self.label_progress, text="the download is complete")
            self.new1.place(in_=self.label_progress, x=50)
```

but it seems like it doesnt want to show each number untill the loop is complete, at the end it just shows a 100. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Without knowing what `Label` is, it's impossible to know what's going on.  Why don't you use this instead: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter` has `mainloop()` which runs all the time and does many thing - ie. it updates data in widget, redraws widgets, executes your function. When `mainloop()` executes your function then it can't updates/redraws widgets till your function stop running. You can use `root.update()` in your function to force tkinter to update/readraw widgets.

Or you can use

```
root.after(miliseconds, function_name)
```

to periodically execute function which will update `Label` . And between executions `tkinter` will have time to update/redraw widgets.

Examples which use `after` to update time in `Label`:

https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after

---

**BTW:** `tkinter` has `ttk.Progressbar`

Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770800/1832058

[image]