# Thread execution calculation

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

how you doing?
I'm fairly new to python, so please bear with me.

I have been working on GUI application using [TKinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), and have implemented Threads already, so here is the part where i am stuck, i want to use progress bar to show the progress of work that is being done within a thread, so how can i calculate that how much that thread has executed? like in percentage? or anything.

any help or pointers will be highly appreciated, Thank you

Comment: use `time` or `datetime` module - but to calculate percentage you have to know time when thread will end its job - and it can be problem.

Comment: The thing is, i'm creating new threads dynamically, so i have no idea how much each thread will take, so even if i want, i can really know time it will take.

Comment: than you can't calculate percentage. You can only use `mode="indeterminate"` and progressbar will display bar as first bar on  image at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770800/1832058